# How to automatically redirect the client with React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

In **React Router v5,** there was a **<Redirect>** component that you could use to redirect the user from one route to another as shown below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
// ...

function App() {
  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/project" element={<Redirect to="/project/list" />} />
        <Route path="/project/list" element={<ProjectListPage />} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However this produces the following error with v6:

[image: export 'Redirect' (imported as 'Redirect') was not found in 'react-router-dom']

Currently the top search result, when I look for "react router redirect" is:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Which is clearly outdated.

Comment: Also, FYI, the `Switch` component was replaced by the `Routes` component. See the [Upgrade from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) guide for other breaking changes between versions.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs changed drastically in **React Router v6.** However the change here seems to be pretty simple, just replace the old **<Redirect>** component with the new **<Navigate>** component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
// ...

function App() {
  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/project" element={<Navigate to="/project/list" />} />
        <Route path="/project/list" element={<ProjectListPage />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can find the updated documentation for React Router v6 here:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate

And a full upgrade guide here:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#

Comment: This is also covered in their [upgrade from v5 to v6 documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory)